# In iOS Game Kit - Connecting devices issues at first time

Tags: ios

Everytime I try to connect the devices by Bluetooh at first time after installing the application it takes too much time to connect or sometime the connection get denied.

Here is my code:

```
(void)setUpSession {
    @try {
        if(mTimeOutTimer) {
            [mTimeOutTimer invalidate];
             mTimeOutTimer = nil;
        }

        self.mConnectionState = ConnectionStateDisconnected;
        if(!mPeerPickerController) {
            mPeerPickerController = [[GKPeerPickerController alloc] init];
            mPeerPickerController.delegate = self;
            mPeerPickerController.connectionTypesMask = GKPeerPickerConnectionTypeNearby;
        }

        //Present Peer Picker.
        [mPeerPickerController show];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Expception Occured at path -> BlueToothManager/setUpSession");
        NSLog(@"Exception Name -> %@",[exception name]);
        NSLog(@"Exception Reason -> %@",[exception reason]);
    }
}

(GKSession *)peerPickerController:(GKPeerPickerController *)picker sessionForConnectionType:(GKPeerPickerConnectionType)type {
    NSString *deviceName = [[UIDevice currentDevice] name];
    GKSession* gkSession = [[GKSession alloc] initWithSessionID:@"BluetoothStreamingVideo" displayName:deviceName sessionMode:GKSessionModePeer];
    gkSession.delegate = self;
    if(self.mGameKitSession) {
        [self.mGameKitSession disconnectFromAllPeers];
        if([self.mGameKitSession isAvailable]) {
            [self.mGameKitSession setAvailable:FALSE];
        }
        [self.mGameKitSession setDataReceiveHandler:nil withContext:nil];
        self.mGameKitSession = nil;
    }
    self.mGameKitSession = gkSession;
    return [gkSession autorelease];
}
```

But once the connection get set, next time connection set well with no long time duration.